# High-frequency compensation implementation

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a YIG oscillator whose being corrected using a servo DC amplifier.
I have built a two-stage amplifier as shown below with 5 MHz BW but I am not sure regarding the compensation part.

In the text below the functionality is described. What is high frequency compensation? What is compensation of high roll of response? If someone could explain to me, what is that in simple words?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Lub2354, I've commented a few times regarding your posts. Your posts repeatedly exhibit the same errors which the community has to correct or interpret. Please conduct a spell check before you post, and use proper capitalization. Formatting your question correctly is part of good engineering, in the sense of communicating clearly with other engineers. I realize English may not be your first language, but do try to not make the same mistakes when they've been pointed out to you.